# Expected Value of a random variable X and its moments given

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Random variable $X$ has moments $E(X)$, $E(X^{2})$, $E(X^{3})$, etc.

(a) Show $E\left[(X - \mu)^{3}\right] = E(X^{3}) - 3 [E(X^{2})] [E(X)] + 2 [E(X)]^{3}$.

(b) Show $E\left[(X - \mu)^{4}\right] = E(X^{4}) - 4 [E(X)] [E(X^{3})] + 6 [E(X)]^{2} [E(X^{2})] - 3 [E(X)]^{4}\ $.

I already tried expanding the equation but I think it's wrong since I'm not getting the whole equation. Anyone here can tell me if I'm missing something? We didn't really discuss the specifics of expected values. Thanks!

Comment: It is $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^3]$ I assume? And can you post how you expanded the equation? It is hard to help if you don't tell us where you are stuck. And I don't think it would be helping you if we just gave you the solution.

Comment: @FelixB. yes, you're correct

Comment: wait i'll upload it

Comment: a. E (X- $\mu \$) $\^{3}\$
= E (X-E(X))  $\^{3}\$
= E [ (X $\^{2}\$ - XE(X) -XE(X) + E(X) $\^{2}\$) (X-E(X))]
= E [ (X $\^{2}\$ - 2XE(X) + E(X) $\^{2}\$) (X-E(X))]

Comment: sorry, ill adjust the codes for the eqns

Comment: looks like you have the right idea - you just need to use linearity at the end and simplify. But I guess you already got a solution.

Comment: @FelixB. okay thanks! I think I just had a problem with my arithmetic too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: $E[X] = \mu$

a) $$E[(X-\mu)^3] =  E[X^3 -3X^2\mu +3X\mu^2 -\mu^3]$$
$$= E[X^3]  -3\mu E[X^2] + 3\mu^2E[X] - E[X]^3$$
$$ = E[X^3] - 3E[X^2]E[X] + 3E[X]^3 - E[X]^3$$
$$= E[X^3] - 3E[X^2]E[X] + 2E[X]^3$$

b) is a similar process.